# Similar Triangles Problem (No corresponding sides)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

[image: The problem]

This problem is from a Year 9 Oxford Maths textbook. I have tried to solve it since yesterday to no avail. Here are the questions - It is only (b/c) that I cannot solve, but I included the other questions since it gives us an idea of the methods that they want us to use:

> a) Using an understanding of angles and parallel lines, explain why the triangles on the right are similar.
>   
> b) Match corresponding sides and find the scale factor between the two triangles.
>   
> c) Find the length of the unknown sides

I tried using the similar triangles method, but I'm not sure whether it is possible, because there are no corresponding sides, since the corresponding sides of 3, 2 and 7.5 are unknown.

I have also tried rotating the smaller triangle into the bigger triangle, to form something like this:

[image: Rotate top triangle into bottom]

From there, I tried to see if I could find the missing variables from comparing the equations but that didn't work either. I found that ab = 15, ac = 22.5 and 2c = 3b, but that didn't help, as a and b had no corresponding sides and were lengths of different triangles. I couldn't find the length of the unknown sides ultimately because there were too many variables.

I also tried using lines to cut the triangles in half to form 90 degree angles but that did not work either, because no angles were specified on the problem. I also tried using interior the interior angles of the triangles to try and find the exterior angles to form "outside triangles" between the two triangles but that didn't work.

How do you solve this problem? I know that there is apparently a specific answer (as shown below), but since there are no corresponding sides, can't any value be placed in a and b, as long as they are to scale?

Here are the answers (mouse over to see):

> a = 2.5, b = 6

I also tried this, but I'm not sure whether it can be proven to be possible. The answer I got by assuming that the height of the triangle was 3 was quite close to the scale factor... When I rounded the scale factor off into a whole number it gave the correct answer for some reason. Can this be proven possible/impossible:
[Triangles rotated into one big triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuDj5.png)

I read the original question on the e-book, but I don't have it now. Here is the original picture of the problem. (very badly taken, question numbers are off the page):
[Original pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVlNC.jpg)

Comment: Does this book require use of rulers or is it just formal arguments?

Comment: I don't think the book mentioned rulers at all. It was also an e-book, rather than a physical copy. If it is unsolvable without supplementary information then it must be that the book wanted us to use rulers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is undetermined as stated. However, you get the answer you quoted with the additional assumption that the red line completes an isosceles triangle having the bottom horizontal segment as its base.

[image]

Whether that's something that you were expected to assume from the picture, or the problem forgot to mention some other condition, that's anybody's guess.

---

[EDIT] Following is the sketch of the proof using the additional assumption.

Let $\alpha$ be the angle in the top left corner. Then, by similarity and the law of cosines:

- $\frac{2}{b} = \frac{a}{7.5}$
- $2^2 = 3^2 + a^2 - 2 \cdot 3 \cdot a \cdot \cos \alpha$
- $(2+b)^2 = 3^2 + (a+7.5)^2 - 2 \cdot 3 \cdot (a+7.5) \cdot \cos \alpha$

Eliminate $\cos \alpha$ between the last two, then solve the remaining two equations in $a,b$.

Comment: Could you please explain the how that would help get the answer?

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 Could YOU explain how that would help get the answer?

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 That would give the $3^{rd}$ constraint required to solve the system.

Comment: @Alephnull I don't understand how assuming that the red line forms an isosceles triangle would help get the answer. Could you show the steps for solving the problem?

Comment: Is that isosceles triangle always there for a figure of this type (disregarding distances)?

Comment: @Alephnull No, definitely not. That's why the problem as posed does *not* have a unique solution *unless* you use some additional hidden assumption. I was just second-guessing what was the hidden assumption that led to the result the OP quoted.

Comment: I have attached the picture of the original problem in the textbook at the end of OP. Not a very good picture though.

Comment: @dxiv BY adding in the answer (a = 2.5), a rough sketch showed such isosceles triangle cannot be formed by adding the red line.

Comment: @Mick The calculations worked out for me. I'll recheck.

Comment: @dxiv sorry for misunderstanding the legs of the said isosceles triangle.

Comment: @Mick You are right, that was ambiguous. I edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Wow, the proof works when substituting in "a" to find cos(A) then substituting in "b". This is my first time asking on the maths stackexchange. Although I am totally convinced that the textbook intended rulers to be used (this was for Y9s!), I'm marking this as the answer because of the proof. How in the world did you ever come up with that equation? It would be great if you can explain how you came up with the proof.

Comment: +1 for asking a clear question with all the necessary context including your own attempts to solve it. About the textbook, I don't even know what Y9 means (or entices), so I find the notion of using *rulers* odd at least. Why not measure the `unknown sides` directly, using the ruler, then? The idea came to me while just eyeballing the picture to second-guess what could make the problem make sense, then it was easy to confirm. As for the equations, the first one you had it already, the other two are straight applications of the law of cosines to the two triangles sharing the angle $\alpha$.

Comment: @dvix Y9 means year 9 (the tenth year of compulsory education in Australia). This question was originally from the Oxford Year 9 Maths textbook.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 By that time in (what would be called here) high school, students would be expected to *not* assume anything unless it's explicitly spelled out (for example, just because the picture shows an angle *may* be $45^{\circ}$ don't assume it *is* $\pi / 4$ unless it's stated so). I would rather guess that your textbook goofed on this particular question, and you did well to call them out on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they want is for you to measure on the figure using a ruler (or measure the angles), and figure out the scale factor using your measurement experimentally. Other than that, there is no way you can find the sides without supplementary information. Note that the parallel sides are found also by observation.

Comment: Perhaps, especially since you confirmed that there is no way to find the sides without any supplementary information. It was in an e-book version, so I did not think that rulers could be used. If there are no other answers I will probably mark this as the answer.